# Troubles with visualization of big graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a undirected graph with 47 nodes and 90 weighted edges. I want to get the image of this graph, but I get something weird[1]: nodes are on top of each other. I want to fix it but I don't know how. Here is the code for drawing:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab


def show_graph(G):
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='#A0CBE2', edge_color='#BB0000', width=2, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues, with_labels=True)
    plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=1000)
    # 2 way
    # nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
    # plt.draw()
    # plt.show()


f = open("europe.txt")
G = nx.Graph()
lines = f.readlines()
edges = list()
for line in lines:
    tmp = line.split(', ')
    tmp[2] = int(tmp[2])
    edges.append(tmp)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
show_graph(G)
```

Image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Slx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and the function

```
def show_graph(G):
    plt.subplot(111)
    nx.draw(G, pos=nx.planar_layout(G), node_color='r', edge_color='b', with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

A planar layout made sense for my situation